# Button to reload the contents of a div which contains php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div containing php that loads a random image from a directory. This bit works fine when i reload the page. The code:

```
<div id="imageArea">

    <?php
        $dir = 'images/assets/';
        $images = scandir($dir);
        $i = rand(2, sizeof($images)-1);
    ?>
    <img src="images/assets/<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" alt="<?php echo str_replace(array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif'), '', $images[$i]); ?>"/>

</div>
```

And further down the page i have another div that contains a button. I want it so that when people click this button it loads a new random image, i guess it would reload the div, but i don't want it to reload the page, is that possible? The button:

```
<div id="newPic">
<input type="button" value="Reload" id="Reload"/>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Reload").click(function(){
        $("#imageArea").html("result reloaded successfully");
    });
});
</script>
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#Reload").click(function(){
     $("#imageArea").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
   });
});
```

I am new to php and javascript and so i have been following other peoples instructions.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

split your php script to another file (just echo the `img tag`), and then use ajax to call that page.

```
$("#reload").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
     url:"demo.php",success:function(ajax_load){
     $("#imageArea").html(ajax_load)
  }});
});
```

**php file**

```
<?php
    $dir = 'images/assets/';
    $images = scandir($dir);
    $i = rand(2, sizeof($images)-1);
?>
<img src="images/assets/<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" alt="<?php echo str_replace(array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif'), '', $images[$i]); ?>"/>
```

Comment: This isn't working, it isn't loading loading an image at all. Im not sure what you meant by "(just echo the img tag)" and so i put everything from the 2nd lot of code into a different php file and replaced "demo.php" with the name of that file, but still no luck. Im not sure what im doing wrong. I then put the 1st lot of code inside script tags inside the div with the button.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use ajax to update the div with the image?

here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#clickme').click(function(){
 var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
$('#contentimg').attr('src','0'+number+'.jpg');
});
});
```

this would work given that the images are in the same folder else give the src of image accordingly

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, please could you give example code?

Comment: every time the button is clicked you want the image to change right?

Comment: please be patient i will get back to you

Comment: please use the following instead of ur line of code: `<img src="images/Assets/<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" alt="<?php echo str_replace(array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif'), '', $images[$i]); ?>" id="imagecontent"/>`

Comment: the script:`$(document).ready(function() {            $('#Reload').click(function() {var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);               $('#imagecontent').attr('src', 'images/Assets/' + '0' + number + '.jpg');   });   });`

Comment: and this line: `$dir = "images/Assets";`

Comment: I ended up putting my php in an external file, and then loading this through an iFrame, you can then refresh the iFrame with an onclick. Thank you for all your help though